# Finding which button is pressed inside a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, html-table

I want to know which button is pressed inside a form... Only thing is those buttons are inside a table. I tried many of the solutions posted in similar questions but they are not working. I have something like:

```
<form>
  <table>
  <tr><td><button value=id>Dosomething</button><td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

I used the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xFvrV/9/ . But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use

```
$(this).attr('id'))
```

in your event handler:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    // save as data on form's .data
    alert('I am ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).parent().data('submitbutton', $(this));
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bJsTm/

Note that you don't have a `data-submitbutton` in your Fiddle, so `.data('submitbutton')` will not return anything.

The fact that the buttons are in a table does not matter.